# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado. Ao consumir operação webservice

Tags: c#, thread, exceção

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
proxy_hom_recepcionarLoteRps.RecepcionarLoteRPS proxy = new 
proxy_hom_recepcionarLoteRps.RecepcionarLoteRPS();

proxy.Url = url + "/arecepcionarloterps";

string resp = proxy.Execute(CABECALHO, xmlEnvio);
```

O Execute é um método importado de um WSDL:

```
public partial class RecepcionarLoteRPS : 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{

    /// <remarks/>
    public RecepcionarLoteRPS()
    {
        this.Url = "http://nfsev-prd.manaus.am.gov.br/nfsev/servlet/arecepcionarloterps";
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.e-nfs.com.braction/ARECEPCIONARLOTERPS.Execute", RequestElementName="RecepcionarLoteRPS.Execute", RequestNamespace="http://www.e-nfs.com.br", ResponseElementName="RecepcionarLoteRPS.ExecuteResponse", ResponseNamespace="http://www.e-nfs.com.br", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Outputxml")]
    public string Execute(string Nfsecabecmsg, string Nfsedadosmsg)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("Execute", new object[] {
                    Nfsecabecmsg,
                    Nfsedadosmsg});
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }
```

O `Execute` chama uma operação de requisição web service, porém algumas vezes, retorna a exceção:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
>      em System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>      em System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>      em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>      em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      em System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      em System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)
>      em nfsews.LinxEnviarLoteRpsImpl.executa(String envio)
>      em nfsews.IntegradorNFSe.LinxEnviarLoteRps(String envio)

Alguém saberia me informar como posso tratar ?

Comment: inclua o código do seu proxy `RecepcionarLoteRPS` e do método `Execute()`

Comment: Incluído. Execute foi importado de um WSDL